# Error 1004 when referencing a dimmed value in query settings

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, powerquery

I'm trying to run an Excel power query against an access database using values form a cell but keep running into an error. I've got close to 0 experience running queries via VBA so ended up getting 90% of the code from a macro recorder, so apologies for the messiness.

I've ran msgboxes against the value to make sure they're pulling everything correctly, i'm just not sure if i'm referencing the dimmed values properly.

```
Sub QueryMacro()
'
' QueryMacro Macro
'

Dim DayRange, MonthRange, YearRange As Range
Dim YR, MR, DR As String
Set DayRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
Set MonthRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
Set YearRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2")
YR = YearRange.Value
MR = MonthRange.Value
DR = DayRange.Value


    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Task Track", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Access.Database(File.Contents(""C:\Folder\Database_be.accdb""), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""_Task Track"" = Source{[Schema="""",Item=""Task Track""]}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""_Task Track"", each [DTE] = #datetime(YR, MR, DR, 0, 0, 0))" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & _
        "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Filtered Rows"""
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Task Track"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Task Track]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = False
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Task_Track"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

To clarify, the error occurs in this section:

```
#""Filtered Rows"" = Table.SelectRows(#""_Task Track"", each [DTE] = #datetime(YR, MR, DR, 0, 0, 0))"
```

where instead of a static date #datetime(2019, 10, 11, 0, 0, 0) i'm trying to reference a dimmed value YR.

It comes back with "Error 1004: [Expression.Error] The import YR matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"

The way I understand it is that it's trying to look up YR in the access database instead of using the value of YR I dimmed.

Help?

Comment: `YR`, `MR`, and `DR` are within the quotes so are not the variables you expect, but the Strings "YR", "MR," and "DR."

Comment: Not cause of error but don't see need for DAY_, Month_, Year_ range object variables. `YR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2")`

Comment: Yes i gathered that much. What i'm trying to figure out is how to have it actually use the variable instead of just using it as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate variables.
Don't think need those Chr(13) and Chr(10) codes.
I use apostrophe instead of doubling quote marks.

Might not be a problem declaring as String but since values are actually numeric, maybe should declare as Integer or Long.

```
Dim YR, MR, DR As String
DR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2")
MR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B2")
YR = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C2")

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Task Track", Formula:="let" & _
        "Source = Access.Database(File.Contents('C:\Folder\Database_be.accdb'), [CreateNavigationProperties=true])," & _
        "#'_Task Track' = Source{[Schema='',Item='Task Track']}[Data]," & _
        "#'Filtered Rows' = Table.SelectRows(#'_Task Track', each [DTE] = #datetime(" & _
        YR & ", " & MR & ", " & DR & ", 0, 0, 0)) in #'Filtered Rows'"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location='Task Track';Extended Properties=''" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
```

Comment: The codes as a whole didn't work - refused to import anything and just sat still, however changing the syntax from #datetime(YR, MR, DR, 0, 0, 0)) to #datetime(" & _
        YR & ", " & MR & ", " & DR & ", 0, 0, 0))  worked like a charm! You're an absolute champion my friend, thank you!